# How to avoid this Unity Prefab Modifications behavior?

Tags: unity-game-engine

### Desc:

There is a component with list data:

```cs
public class TestPrefab : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<string> DataList;
}
```

Then I create a prefab with this component like this:
[image]

Then I drag the prefab into scene, modify the component data like this ("Data1"=>"Data1_Modified") **(I wont apply changes because I just wanna keep it as a prefab instance, which has some changes from the origin prefab)**:
[image]

Then back to the prefab stage, delete the first data:
[image]

Then the prefab instance in the scene comes to:
[image]

### How does it happen?

unity save this modification like this:
[image]
so unity just change the first data in the list to "Data1_Modified", rather than change "Data1" to "Data1_Modified".

### Question:

Is there any elegant method to avoid this unpredicted behavior?

Comment: Are you using a custom editor for this? But yes, it does indeed look like Unity is storing the location of the override, not a data patch.

Comment: @Immersive Yes, I use "Odin" to enhance inspector, it has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: All good.  It looked like Odin, which is indeed no problem, but wanted to be sure 

Answer (score -1):

you should apply this edits on prefabs so after you finish in inspector menu press on **overrides** then **apply all** 
[image]

prefabs are prefabricated objects so to update them from **Scene window** you need to tell editor to apply your changes on prefabs.

Comment: OP has made a local override to a prefab which he wishes to remain local, he then makes a change to the prefab. The question is why does the local override remain when the list item it was overriding was removed.  The answer is that Unity only tracks the location of the override, not the specific item that is being overridden.